# Custom background not showing

Tags: theme-development, custom-background

I'm writing my own theme and i have a problem with body background

My code in functions.php

```
if (! function_exists('anime_quotes_setup')){
function anime_quotes_setup(){
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', [
        'height'      => 50,
        'width'       => 100,
        'flex-width'  => false,
        'flex-height' => false,
        'header-text' => '',
        'unlink-homepage-logo' => false, // WP 5.5
    ] );

    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', [
        'default-color'          => '#F87C7C',
        'default-image'          => '',
    ] );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'anime_quotes_setup');
}
```

When i change background image or color in admin panel it's showing changes on editor, but in other tabs it's still without any changes.

[image]

[image]

In html code i see this

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
   body.custom-background { background-color: #f87c7c; }
</style>
```

but it still doesn't work